# Adding Events to Google Calendar Shared To Me

Tags: google-calendar-api

If I have several Google Calendars, I can create a new event and pick which one I want to go into from a drop down menu.

Now let's assume some other Google Calendar owner created a new calendar and then shared that calendar to me. Let's assume they did this right and gave me permission to edit events, maybe even to further share the calendar

**How do I now add events to the calendar shared with me?** When I add an event to the calendar interface while logged in as myself, I do not have the option to select the other person's calendar, even though I should have edit permission on it. It defaults to just my calendar, but even on the drop down menus I don't have other options.

I'm actually trying to create a two-way sync between the two calendars. Ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Are you trying to do this programmatically via the Google Caledar API or are you trying to do this in the user interface?

If programmatically, use the following API method substituting the calendarId with your friend's calendarId:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

If you're trying to do this in the UI, your friend needs to go to `calendar settings > Share this Calendar > Share with specific people`, and specifically list your email address with the permission settings at least "make changes to events". This will place your friend's calendar in the "My calendars" section of your calendar interface. At this point, when you create new events, the drop down box will allow you to select your friend's calendar.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem described here. You already have access to the calendar, the person has already done what you said in your UI solution (no one mentioned an API), yet when you try to create a new event, the shared calendar is not in the drop-down menu of possible calendars for the event to go into. Also, an existing event cannot be edited by the drop down menu method you would use if you had multiple of your own calendars.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if someone shares a calendar with you, and they've given you edit permission, you should be able to see that calendar as an option on that drop-down calendar, and just add events like you would ordinarily.

However, if that person sharing the calendar has special permissions (e.g. it's a Google Suite calendar that has appointments) you may not be able to edit it really, despite the supposed settings. It might be that whoever has administrative privileges can fix this for you though, I don't know. I'm working on that myself but decided to give a second answer here in case I never find out but it still helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as the reporter here, but after too much searching I found that the problem is the user's (account) permissions for the calendar: the default is to only allow viewing an event (`See all event details (Default)`), but the actual permissions value needed to *add* a new event is `Make changes to events`.  Users with that permission can do the following:

```
  Make changes to events:
    - Find details for all events, including private ones.
    - Add and edit events.
    - Restore or permanently delete events from the calendar’s trash.
    - Find the time zone setting for the calendar.
    - Subscribe to email alerts when events are created, changed, cancelled, RSVPed to, or coming up.
```

These permissions are described in detail at https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082#controlaccess&zippy=%2Cunderstand-permission-settings-for-shared-calendars

In short, the admin of the shared calendar must change the settings for your user account, in the settings of that calendar.